# Closing QMainWindows connected to button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a program that is assembled as follows:

[image]

A brief explanation is that the two GUI windows are added into a mdisubarea window. And on each of the GUI windows, there is a button that opens another window. My issue is that when I close MainWindow, the Calculate Window & Image Window do not close with it. My question is, how do I make sure that all windows close when I close MainWindow? Or, if I can add the windows from the buttons to the mdisubarea somehow.

Code:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzcHlfStubD3R0VBTWZDQXp1bWc

Comment: MainWindow is the main window, if you close this window, all windows should be closed. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your code is not reproducible since copying it and running it lacks components.

Comment: Correct, the MlS and VlS windows close, that's because they are added as a subwindow, only the windows that open when user clicks the button don't close, because they aren't apart of the mdisubarea window, they are there own window. I was showing the main parts of the code to see if I am creating the window that opens from the button correctly

Comment: Show an mvce, please

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzcHlfStubD3R0VBTWZDQXp1bWc

Comment: Run ValueProgram to start program, and then open MlS window, click button and window should open, then exit the main program, and the window from the button stays open,also happens with Settings window to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent parameter is so that when the parent class is removed the children also do it, in your case you have not done it, to solve in your case you must pass the instance to a Reference:

```
self.Image = Reference(self)
```

Another thing is that you should call the parent constructor when you inherit, in your case you called QWidget instead of QMainWindow, you should switch to the following:

```
class Reference(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_ReferenceImage()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```